# Setting default encoding to utf-8 in perl conditionally on command-line option

Tags: perl, encoding, utf-8

In order to process text in utf-8 in Perl, I have been using `binmode(<file-handle>, ":encoding(UTF-8)");` on each stream I use. I just discovered that

```
use open ( ":encoding(UTF-8)", ":std" );
```

can be used to do the same thing globally. This is great, since it means a lot less repetitive code.

But now I have a problem: I would like to have a command line option to my script, `-utf8`, which turns everything utf-8 only when supplied. Since `use open` is a pragma, it is lexically scoped and I cannot put it in an if statement, but without an if statement it cannot depend on command line options.

Here is a minimal example illustrating the problem, call it problem.pl

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# hard-coded in my minimal example, normally set by command line option -utf8
my $use_utf8 = 1;

# use only applies within its lexical scope - this does not work
if ($use_utf8) {
   use open ( ":encoding(UTF-8)", ":std" );
}

# if I put it at the right lexical scope, it's not conditional on $use_utf8
#..e open ( ":encoding(UTF-8)", ":std" );

while (<>) {
   print length($_);
}
```

When I run this code on a file, call in `input`, containing one line with a 2-byte UTF-8 character, say `à`, it outputs 3:

```
$ ./problem.pl input
3
```

If I move the `use open` statement to the global scope, I get the expected results of a length of 2 (one character plus one newline):

```
$ ./problem.pl input
2
```

So how can I set the encoding to utf-8 globally, but conditionally on a command-line option, so that I would get 2 with `-utf8` but 3 without.

Also, in my real use case, I use the spaceship operator (`while (<>)`) to provide high flexibility in the command line syntax to process multiple files, but in this case I can't call `binmode` since the file handles are managed automatically by Perl. `use open` would be a much nicer option, if I could make it conditional.

PS: Yes, I really do still have non-utf8 data that I want to continue to be able to handle. Thank God most of our data is now in utf-8, but unfortunately not all of it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: you can use [if](https://perldoc.pl/if) to conditionally apply a lexical pragma. Just make sure the condition is available at compile time (you may need to use a BEGIN block before).

```
my $use_utf8;
BEGIN { $use_utf8 = 1; }
use if $use_utf8, 'open', ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

The [-C](https://perldoc.pl/perlrun#-C-%5Bnumber/list%5D) option works similarly to the open pragma for utf8 layers. `-CSD` will set it on the standard handles (S) and any handles opened (D). Unfortunately it uses the less safe `:utf8` layer instead of `:encoding(UTF-8)`, so you may end up with broken strings if you use it for input that is not actually UTF-8. Also, `-CD` sets a default for any handles opened in the whole program, not just the lexical scope of your script, this can possibly break usage of modules that don't expect it. (`-CS` is always global, as is the ':std' effect of the open pragma, since the standard handles are global.)

```
perl -CSD problem.pl input
```

Comment: Cool, works nicely. It would have never occurred to me to do command-line parsing in a BEGIN block, but it works, so why not. It means declaring the variables for my options outside the BEGIN block instead of inside my `GetOptions()` as a like to do, but that's an easy detail to fix. I just learned the `use if...` syntax today.

Comment: About `-C`: besides the less safe `:utf8`, I really hate to call my scripts explicitly with `perl ... script name`, so your first solution is by far my preferred choice. I did find out about `-C` in my research, and I think it's an option to remember for when I want to make a script utf8 friendly temporarily without modifying it.

Comment: @joanis It's because `use`, and lexical scopes, are both compile-time concepts.